# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' for Firefox and IE edge

Tags: sql-server, internet-explorer, firefox

I got a new machine window 10 pro and setup IIS 10 for web application using dot net 4.5.2.
My web.config use

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

My db connection

```
Data Source=ServerName;Database=DBName;Integrated Security=True;
```

When I run application locally, IE 11 and Chrome works without problem, but IE edge and Fire Fox version 47 get login failed error for DataSet.

```
Dim adapterName As New BasicTableAdapters.NamesTableAdapter
Dim Name As String = ""
Name = adapterName.GetName("ID") 'This line get error
```